# Is there a C function for this kind of printing?

Tags: c, function, output

I only know and only use `printf()`, but I want to try a function that can output something without the use of `%` parameters.

I want to do something like this:

```c
printf("Hello, %s.\n", name);
```

But no longer using `%` for it. Something like:

```c
foo("Hello, ");
foo(name);
foo(".\n");
```

Is there a function that acts like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`fputs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs)

```
fputs("Hello, ", stdout);
fputs(name, stdout);
puts(".");
```

Note that this can only print strings, not other types of data like you can with `printf()`. There's `putc()` and `fputc()` for single characters.

There's also `puts()` that writes only to `stdout`, but it also adds a newline at the end, so you can't use it as a replacement for your `printf()`, except for the last part that ends with newline.